# server doesn't receive message from client(android)

Tags: android, client

i tried my client(both client&server) code in neatbeans, everything worked fine. then i wrote it in eclipse sdk and i was trying to run it in emulator, server didn't receive message anymore...

client:

```
package com.aaa.udep;

import com.aaa.udep.Client;
import com.aaa.udep.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Thread thread=new Thread (new Client());
                thread.start();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

package com.aaa.udep;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.util.Log;

public class Client implements Runnable {

Client()
{
    run();
}
    @Override

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            try {
                Log.i("MyApp", "starting");
              String messageStr = "Hello Android dolwno rabotatj, nado testirovatj na teelefone!";
              String serverHostname = new String ("127.0.0.1");  
              DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(); 
              InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverHostname); 
              Log.i("MyApp", "Atempting to connect");

              byte[] sendData = new byte[1024]; 
              byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];           
             sendData = messageStr.getBytes();

             Log.d ("MyAPp","Sending data to server");
              DatagramPacket sendPacket = 
                 new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9879); 

              clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
              Log.d ("MyAPp","Sent");

              DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
                 new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 

              Log.d ("MyApp","Waiting for return packet");
              clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);

              try {
                   clientSocket.receive(receivePacket); 
                   String modifiedSentence = 
                       new String(receivePacket.getData()); 

                   InetAddress returnIPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

                   int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                   Log.d ("From server at get reply: ", serverHostname);
                   Log.d("Message: ", modifiedSentence ); 

                  }
              catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
                  {

            ste.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Timeout Occurred: Packet assumed lost", ste+"");
              }

              clientSocket.close(); 
             }
           catch (UnknownHostException ex) { 
             ex.printStackTrace();
             Log.e("UnknownHostException", ex+"");
            }
           catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             Log.e("IO Expeption", ex+"");

            }
        }
    }
manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

logs:

```
03-28 00:53:37.159: I/MyApp(337): starting
03-28 00:53:37.159: I/MyApp(337): Atempting to connect
03-28 00:53:37.220: D/MyAPp(337): Sending data to server
03-28 00:53:37.220: D/MyAPp(337): Sent
03-28 00:53:37.220: D/MyApp(337): Waiting for return packet
03-28 00:53:47.254: W/System.err(337): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
03-28 00:53:47.860: W/System.err(337):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:263)
03-28 00:53:47.860: W/System.err(337):  at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:414)
03-28 00:53:47.870: W/System.err(337):  at com.aaa.udep.Client.run(Client.java:51)
03-28 00:53:47.870: W/System.err(337):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-28 00:53:47.870: E/Timeout Occurred: Packet assumed lost(337): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
```

Comment: It clearly says connection timeout..Make sure that your network connection is available and also your server is responding to the requests

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator doesn't share the same IP address as your PC, which means you can't use  the loop-back ip *127.0.0.1* and expect it to connect to your PC.
Android emulator instances run on a virtual LAN that has its own firewall and subnet and it can communicate with your PC via an IP on that subnet.

wich is : `10.0.2.2`

for more about emulator networking visit [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).

Hope that helps